# snakemake --list-code-changes does not propagate into subworkflows

Tags: snakemake

I use

```
snakemake -R `snakemake --list-code-changes`
```

to rerun rules in which the code has changed. However, this does not seem to work when using subworkflows, for example:

Main Snakefile:

```
rule all:
  input: "out"

subworkflow subworkflow:
  workdir: "subworkflow"

rule run_subworkflow:
  input: subworkflow("subworkflow_output")
  output: "out"
  shell: "cat {input} > {output}"
```

Subworkflow Snakefile:

```
rule all:
  input: "subworkflow_output"

rule generate_b:
  output: "subworkflow_output"
  shell: "echo 'subworkflow' > {output}"
```

Changes made in the shell command of the subworkflow are not detected.

Is this expected behaviour?